# How to send the parameter in a string using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing, laravel-5

When I use Form::select,  inside I can pass an attribute parameter that is an array, but I have problems concatenating the Id with the rest of the string

```
{!! Form::select('product_category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => '','onchange' => 'addComboCategory(this, null,\'ajax_product_category\', \'ajax_product_info\', \'?parameter_id=2\')']) !!}
```

The method:

```
'onchange' => 'addComboCategory(this, null,\'ajax_product_category\', \'ajax_product_info\', \'?parameter_id=2\')
```

The parameter:

```
\'?parameter_id=2\'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
'onchange' => "addComboCategory(this, null, 'ajax_product_category', 'ajax_product_info', '?parameter_id=2')"
```

With variable:

```
$id = 2;

'onchange' => "addComboCategory(this, null, 'ajax_product_category', 'ajax_product_info', '?parameter_id={$id}')"
```